# Shortcut to Paste & Cut selection at the same time in Sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, copy-paste, sublimetext3

I was wondering if there is a shortcut to Paste from the clipboard & at the same time cut the selection to be pasted somewhere else.

**Elaborating the Question:**

I find myself often swapping values among various sections of code. As a primitive example:

```
var a = "two";
var b = "one";
```

To swap them, I would:

1. cut the value of `a`
2. Paste it next to the value of `b`
3. cut the original value of `b`
4. paste that back as the value of `a`

I was wondering id there is a shortcut to combine step 2 & 3 of this process.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you please elaborate with an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sublime Text provides a tool for doing exactly(?) what you wish.

1. Double click "one" (to select it)
2. Hold ctrl and double click "two" (both are selected now)
3. press ctrl + t to swap selections

Otherwise you may wish to register a new key binding for your custom operation. You can do this via Preferences -> Key bindings (User).

Comment: Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 3):

Use Permute Selection > Reverse:

1. highlight `two` value
2. hold <kbd>control</kbd>
3. highlight `one` value
4. Edit > permute selection > reverse

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, but something is kinda there to help in such situations. There is a Clipboard History built-in Sublime Text (atleast in 3, not sure 2). Just copy the text you are replacing, then press `<C-k><C-v>`. This will popup a small window with clipboard's history. Select the previous copied text to replace currently selected text.

This option is available under `Edit -> Paste from History`.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can do it too with a clipboard history https://github.com/colinta/SublimeClipboardManager

Copy: one
Copy: two
Paste-previous in two
Paste-next in one

The good thing is that clipboard history can be helpful in more situations